# mysql обрезает большое текстовое поле в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT q.*, a.answer
FROM `questions` q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT question_id, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '|| ') answer
    FROM answers
    GROUP BY question_id
 ) a ON q.uid = a.question_id
 WHERE q.deleted = 0
 GROUP BY q.uid
```

Этот запрос выбирает вопросы и ответы к ним, склеивая их. В табличке ответы хранятся в виде `text`. При выборке и конкатенации часть текста обрезается. Например если у меня 3 больших ответа, мне возвращает где-то целый первый ответ и половину второго. Если в базе все эти ответы сделать маленькими - все отлично. В чем здесь проблема?

Comment: SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

Comment: оформите пожалуйста как ответ, а я отмечу. Может кому другому пригодится.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У функции `GROUP_CONCAT` есть ограничение на объем выводимых данных. По умолчанию 1024 символа для каждого объединения - для каждой выводимой строки. Если размер данных, полученных в результате конкатенации, больше, выводимый текст будет обрезан.

Чтобы расширить размер, нужно выполнить команду:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

или `SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` (аналогична предыдущей).

Но данная команда будет применена только к текущей сессии. По завершении сессии, например, при открытии нового соединения, значение данной переменной вернётся к начальному значению.  Для установки глобальной переменной нужно выполнить следующую команду:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```