# SET SESSION объединить с SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

В запросе к базе данных используется GROUP_CONCAT. [Чтобы увеличить количество символов для выводимой строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/579137/219617), нужно использовать

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Как лучше объединить SET SESSION с SELECT? Имеет ли смысл использовать [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php)? Например, так

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; SELECT url, title, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<cite>', a.author, '</cite>', b.comment) separator '\n') FROM comment b, author a WHERE b.id_post = p.id AND a.id = b.id_author ORDER BY b.id) comment FROM post p WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1;")) {
    do {
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
             $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
             $result->free();
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

Смущает наличие цикла do..while, хотя требуется одна строка.

SET GLOBAL не могу применить, так как используется виртуальный хостинг.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите делать отдельными запросами? Сначала SET SESSION, а потом обычный SELECT?

Comment: "Пересылка: на сервер нескольких выражений в одном запросе уменьшает количество клиент-серверных взаимодействий". Но я даже не догадываюсь какая там может быть выгода по времени.

Comment: @НатальяМитрофанова если у вас идет непрерывное взаимодействие с сервером, по тыще обращений в секунду - может быть имеет смысл заморачиваться, но это крайне редко встречаемая задача и там уже обычно используют другие методы оптимизации

Comment: @НатальяМитрофанова оптимизацию надо использовать, когда вы понимаете, что это действительно узкое место в приложении.

Comment: Ага, то есть: "работает и хорошо, не заморачивайся, можно сделать и так и эдак". :) Или лучше делать двумя запросами?